# "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined" in chrom extension nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, openai-api, chatgpt-api

**Objective:**

I am new to nodejs.
Currently creating a chrome extension which should:

- read up title of the current webpage
- use it in a prompt template for chatgpt
- call chatgpt openai api to get a response
- display it in the chrome extension popup

**Current Code Snippet:**
I have a file popup.js which has the following content:

```
async function getGPT3Reponse(text)
  {
    const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
    require("dotenv").config();
    const configuration = new Configuration({
      apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });
    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
    const messages = [];
    messages.push({ role: "user", content: text });

    const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: messages,
    });

    const completion_text = completion.data.choices[0].message.content;
    return completion_text;

  }


const mainText = await fetchMainTextFromTab();
console.log("maintext:", mainText);
const response = await getGPT3Reponse(mainText);


const responseArea = document.getElementById('responseArea');
responseArea.innerHTML = `<p>${response.choices[0].text}</p>`;
```

Package.json has `type:"commonjs"`.

**Error:**
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined

Can someone please help me understand how to fix this?
I have very similar code of getGPT3Reponse in a seperate file "test.js" which I am able to execute in my local VSCode terminal.

Comment: Chrome extensions do not run in node.js

Comment: That is a surprise to me! Sorry for being a newbie.
Is there any sample code you may point to where I can see how to call chatpgt API to use webpage's title to make a prompt, and then display in chrome extension popup?